# Basic crontab not working

Tags: cron, cron-task

I'm trying to create a sample cron job.

First I've edited crontab using:

```
crontab -e
```

Then I've added this line in order to create a test folder in my home every minute:

```
1 * * * * mkdir -p /home/<myusername>/foo/
```

Then I've made sure that cron was running:

```
root       913     1  0 Aug22 ?        00:00:00 cron
```

However if I try to restart it for example (or stop it):

```
restart cron
```

I get the following error message:

> restart: Rejected send message, 1 matched rules; type="method_call",
>   sender=":1.73" (uid=1000 pid=17887 comm="restart cron ")
>   interface="com.ubuntu.Upstart0_6.Job" member="Restart" error
>   name="(unset)" requested_reply="0" destination="com.ubuntu.Upstart"
>   (uid=0 pid=1 comm="/sbin/init")

Also the test folder it's not created.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This cronjob is executed once an hour. The first field is minutes. Try putting a star in there.